# Using Grafana and Prometheus to see stat of another server

Tags: networking, prometheus, grafana

I have installed Grafana and Prometheus on Server-A. Also I've installed "[Node Exporter Full](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter)" on it to see a dashboard like this:

[image]

As you can see, it's showing the resource usage of Server-A. Now I want to know, is it possible to get those reports and statistics of another server (like Server-B)? If yes, is it needed to install something on Server-B?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it. You must install node exporter on every server you want to get metrics then add it as a job in prometheus config file to scrape those metrics.